# How to increase the height of plan geometry in three js?

Tags: github

I have created the plane geometry with some default height and then on certain action(dat UI to increase the height) i want to change the height of plan based on user inputs.How can i do that without creating new PlaneGeometry?

Comment: add code to show us what you have done please

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dat UI I would look here
https://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#1--Basic-Usage

The base idea is that your Three.js (or any graphical animation) has an `animate()` function that should be running as much as up to 60 times per second. The idea is that you change the variable it reads every frame and so by changing the `heightOfPlane += 2` the animation frame will see it and update accordingly